# Howdo you mutate a specific field in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo

Ok, so I have a data structure called product. This product has a field variant with 2 attributes: variant_name (str: e.g. "Size") and variant_options (repeatable).
A variant_option has 3 attributes. A text_option (str: e.g. "S, M, L..."), an inventory_stock (int) and locked_stock (int).

Now I need a query that only updates the locked_stock value for a specific variant_option (S, M, L...) in the "Size" variant, for a specific product (via ID).

The Query that I have right now looks like this:

```
mutation Mutation($updateProductId: ID!, $data: ProductInput!) {
  updateProduct(id: $updateProductId, data: $data) {
    data {
      attributes {
        variant {
          variant_option {
            locked_stock
            text_option
            inventory_stock
          }
          variant_name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The variable data for that Mutation looks like this:

```
{
  "updateProductId": "14",
  "data": {
    "variant": {
      "variant_name": "Size",
      "variant_option": {
        "locked_stock": 50,
        "inventory_stock": 1000,
        "text_option": "M"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't only update the locked_stock value. It deletes the whole "Size" variant and creates a new one that only contains the information from the data object above.

How can I only update the locked_stock value?

Answer (score 0):

Simply refetch the id and (only) the fields that you want to update on the frontend side. Apollo will automatically update the product value that corresponds to that id.